# Worklight 6.2 - Error in Mobile Browser Simulator

Tags: mobile, browser, ibm-mobilefirst, simulator

Using Worklight 6.2

1. I deployed the application into Worklight Server
2. I open the Worklight Console and click on 'Preview'
3. I could not see the Mobile Browser Simulator; the browser only displays the index.html page of the application without the Mobile Browser Simulator.
4. There is stacktrace in the Worklight Console.
5. I am pasting a portion of the stacktrace below.

-

```
[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class    'sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.writev0:-2'

java.io.IOException: Broken pipe

    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.writev0(Native Method)

    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:51)

    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148)

    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:524)

    at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.write(SocketChannel.java:493)

    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NioSocketIOChannel.write(NioSocketIOChannel.java:206)

    at [internal classes]

    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.PreviewServlet.handleAsLooseWorkspaceFile(PreviewServlet.java:206)

    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.PreviewServlet.respondToRequest(PreviewServlet.java:115)

    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.WebServingServletBase.doGetOrPost(WebServingServletBase.java:87)

    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.WebServingServletBase.doGet(WebServingServletBase.java:71)

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)

    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1239)

    at [internal classes]

    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:205)

    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)

    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:209)

    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)

    at [internal classes]




[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.writev0:-2'

java.io.IOException: Broken pipe

    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.writev0(Native Method)

    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:51)

    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148)

    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:524)

    at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.write(SocketChannel.java:493)

    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NioSocketIOChannel.write(NioSocketIOChannel.java:206)

    at [internal classes]

    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.PreviewServlet.handleAsLooseWorkspaceFile(PreviewServlet.java:206)

    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.PreviewServlet.respondToRequest(PreviewServlet.java:115)

    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.WebServingServletBase.doGetOrPost(WebServingServletBase.java:87)

    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.WebServingServletBase.doGet(WebServingServletBase.java:71)

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)

    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1239)

    at [internal classes]

    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:205)

    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)

    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:209)

    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)

    at [internal classes]




[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.writev0:-2'

java.io.IOException: Broken pipe

    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.writev0(Native Method)

    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:51)

    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148)

    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:524)

    at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.write(SocketChannel.java:493)

    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NioSocketIOChannel.write(NioSocketIOChannel.java:206)

    at [internal classes]

    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.PreviewServlet.handleAsLooseWorkspaceFile(PreviewServlet.java:206)

    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.PreviewServlet.respondToRequest(PreviewServlet.java:115)

    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.WebServingServletBase.doGetOrPost(WebServingServletBase.java:87)

    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.WebServingServletBase.doGet(WebServingServletBase.java:71)

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)

    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1239)

    at [internal classes]

    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:205)

    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)

    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:209)

    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)

    at [internal classes]




[ERROR   ] FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe

com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe

    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport.constructErrorReport(WebAppErrorReport.java:153)

    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport.constructErrorReport(WebAppErrorReport.java:194)

    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:830)

    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:461)

    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:127)

    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:88)

    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:205)

    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)

    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:209)

    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)

    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:85)

    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:968)

    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1056)

    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4510)

    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:282)

    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:954)

    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:252)

    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:584)

    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.executeWork(Worker.java:439)

    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.run(Worker.java:421)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Question: What could have caused this problem?

Comment: What environment did you preview from the Worklight console? Or is this on click of "Preview as Common Resources", which does not open the Mobile Browser Simulator. Also what OS and Java version and browser are being used?

Comment: OS: MacOS X 10.9.4
JRE: 1.7.0_60-ea
Safari: 7.0.6 (9537.78.2)
Worklight: 6.2.0.00 (will provide the exact build no)

Answer (score 1):

It is very possible that you have another instance of JVM running that are doing the same thing, perhaps you can kill the java process and try again.